# UITableView load more when scrolling to bottom using Rxswift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I am working with web api which load array of data. But the size of data is big, So I want to apply lazy loading, data on demand technique so that I can quickly load small chunk of data and when user reach the last element of tableview cell then it can load next chunk of data. I want to know is it possible with Rxswift?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this liabrary. Set query amount and index when loading data. 
https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxPager